What is the name/terminology for this application of OLS regression
I don't come from a statistics background and was instructed to follow these steps to fill in missing data. I'm wondering if there is a name for this specific method so that I can learn more of it and its assumptions.
Given a datasets from multiple stations of varying proximity to the station of interest. Each station's datasets are of varying completeness. Impute missing data from the station of interest by applying OLS regression to predict missing values. The motivation for using OLS regression over other models is for "simplicity"

iterate through the stations in order of proximity (as closer stations likely have stronger correlation to the point of interest)

In each iteration, create a OLS model using the select station as the predictor dataset (X) and the station of interest as the target dataset (y). Use the model to impute missing target values.


By doing the specified process with each station dataset, this should create an extended, and more complete dataset for the station of interest

Is this a valid way to apply OLS regression (i.e. would the results make sense)? Is there a specific name for this type of application of OLS regression? Or should we just be using other regression models for something like this?

As mentioned by @Sextus-Empiricus this is a form of imputation. From your data description (spatial data), I presume there are better options though, for instance kriging.

Seconding @Durden 's comment: what you are describing, where you want to put more weight on closer stations, is exactly kriging (aka Gaussian process regression). This kind of thing is an extremely typical application of that model.

I was thinking of kriging as well (which can be seen as a sort of weighted regression as being some form of OLS or GLS). In the case of some simple linear regression it relates to a Savitzky Golay filter.

Is there a specific name for this type of application of OLS regression?
This sounds like 'regression imputation'. An early use of the term is by Little and Rubin in 1982 (although there are some earlier occurances) who described it as

regression imputation, where the missing variables for a unit are
estimated by predicted values from regression on the known
variables for that unit (Buck, 1960).

And they refer to an article by Buck from 1960 as an early occurance of the method.
Little, Roderick JA, and Donald B. Rubin. Incomplete Data: Encyclopedia Entry. University of Wisconsin-Madison. Mathematics Research Center, 1982.
Buck, Samuel F. "A method of estimation of missing values in multivariate data suitable for use with an electronic computer." Journal of the Royal Statistical Society: Series B (Methodological) 22.2 (1960): 302-306.
Is this a valid way to apply OLS regression (i.e. would the results make sense)?
One will have to take into account that the imputed values can not be counted as true measurements and the variation/error in the estimates will be less. In addition, the method is sensitive to bias and it is subjective due to choices made in the type of regression that is to be used.
Or should we just be using other regression models for something like this?
In this particular case of spatial data and data points available in the neighbourhood, something like a kriging regression (mentioned in the comments by Burden) might be useful. Such regression could be viewed as a 'mean imputation' with the addition of giving different weights to points based on the distance/location.

The revision is good!
